# How to set policy for IAM user group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm new to AWS. I have an AWS CodeArtifact repository and I wanted to create a Repository Policy using an IAM user group for the repository.

My Repository Policy using IAM user looks like this.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::****:user/*********"
            },
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:DescribePackageVersion",
                "codeartifact:DescribeRepository",
                "codeartifact:GetPackageVersionReadme",
                "codeartifact:GetRepositoryEndpoint",
                "codeartifact:ListPackages",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersions",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionAssets",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionDependencies",
                "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I do it for a user group ?

I tried to do like what I had done with IAM user for group but there seems to be some error.
It looked like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*****:group/*********"
            },
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:DescribePackageVersion",
                "codeartifact:DescribeRepository",
                "codeartifact:GetPackageVersionReadme",
                "codeartifact:GetRepositoryEndpoint",
                "codeartifact:ListPackages",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersions",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionAssets",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionDependencies",
                "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you **can't do this**:

```
"Principal": {
       "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*****:group/*********"
   },
```

The **IAM groups can't** be used as principles. Usually when you have `AWS` type principle, you are limited to **IAM role** or **IAM user**.

In general though ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html)):

> You can specify any of the following **principals in a policy**:

```
AWS account and root user

IAM users

Federated users (using web identity or SAML federation)

IAM roles

Assumed-role sessions

AWS services

Anonymous users (not recommended)
```

Therefore, the permissions for your AWS CodeArtifact repository could be associated with an **IAM role**. Your group members would have permission of `sts:AssumeRole` for the role. This way they could assume the role, and the role could be used as a principle in your policy.

Answer (score 1):

IAM groups are not a principal, so unfortunately you **cannot use these as a reference** within your policy.

You are limited to either an **IAM user** or **IAM role**.

AWS principals must be the **calling resource** (the resource that attempts to access this service via the API), IAM group constructs are an organisational unit that are applied to users to improve the management of policies.

The only **suggestion** (as per any other resource policy) would be to **create a role** for this group that can be assumed by any user in the group. You would then update the principal to be this role, rather than list all the groups. If this does not work for your solution then you'll need to list all the IAM users.

**If** you create a role you can assume it either [via the console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html), via the [command line](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-cli/) or even via the SDK